# Play videos with LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, video

Is there a way to play videos with LibGDX?

I want to put a video as my splash screen in Android, but I dont want to use the Android SDK, because I am using LibGDX and I am almost finished :/

Comment: There is a LibGDX cross platform video rendering extension: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Playing video with LibGDX has been [defined as out of scope](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=146) for the project. So **no**, you cannot play videos using LibGDX.

This does not preclude the possibility of writing code specific to Android to play videos though. It just means your application won't maintain the portability of LibGDX.

Comment: :( ok thanks for that answer :/ I suppose that I have to use Android SDK, thanks :)

Comment: I did it with Android :)

I created a new Activity and a new Layout, and when the video finishes its playback, I start the activity that has the call to libGDX

Comment: Nice! That was fast, I guess it wasn't too hard to do after all.

Comment: @Rudy_TM please add this as the accepted answer -- that you got around it with a new Activity. That will help others who have the same question later.

Comment: It's pretty easy to write platform specific code in libgdx, so just because it doesn't support video out of the box doesn't mean it can't be done, as your answer implies.

Comment: @Matsemann The question was if it was possible to play videos with LibGDX. It's not. Of course you can write code specific to the platform you're developing on. My answer does not preclude that. And the OP knows that as seen in their first comment. I've updated my answer to make that clear.

Comment: This was defined as out of scope in 2011, now there is a gdx-video module that may or may not work for OP. https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video

Answer (score 20):

As Byte56 said, in libGDX you cannot play videos :( so i did this:

I created a new activity "SplashScreen"

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        String fileName = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() +"/raw/video";

         VideoView vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface);
         vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
         vv.setOnCompletionListener(this);
         vv.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, libgdx.class);
        startActivity(intent);      
        finish();
    }
}
```

In the "onCompletion" method, I use the intent to call my new activity where the "initialize" call for the libGDX engine to work

And a new layout for the videoView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

    </VideoView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting this answer, it will be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: You are welcome :) I spent two days trying different things XD and this was the last one :P

Comment: It's always the last one right? I guess because you stop looking after that :p. Also congrats on nearly being done!

Comment: @Rudy_TM libgdx.class give me an error (libgdx cannot be resolved to a type), how to fix it ?

Comment: @LeSam Instead of libgdx.class, use the name of your Activity that has the entry point of your Libgdx project, "Activity".class

Comment: @Rudy_TM thanks you, I had solved the issue, but now I'm having another problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639096/java-android-set-internal-path-for-videoview

Comment: How can I make the program start with the splash screen and not the MainActivity. It just skips the splashScreen class.

Comment: @G3tinmybelly in your manifest change your splash screen to the launcher activity instead of the MainActivity,

Answer (score -1):

This is the way to play: libname is "indiespot-media-0.8.09.jar" which you can get [here](http://indiespot.net/files/projects/medialib/).

How to use:

1. Download full zip
2. Copy lib folder in the root of project (ffmpeg will be opened by lib with path ./lib/ffmpeg/ffmpeg@os postfix@)
3. 

```java
player = new MoviePlayer(videoFile);
Texure playerTexture = new Texture(
  player.movie.width(), 
  player.movie.height(), 
  Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888) {

  @Override
  public void bind() {
    Gdx.gl.glBindTexture(0, player.textureHandle);
  }
};
```

4. use `playerTexture` as usual texture